# Thunderbird 'attach folder' addon?

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, attachments

I like to drag files into a new Thunderbird message to attach them. This works nicely for individual files but not for folders/directories.

I'd like to be able to drag a folder into a new message and have one of the following occur:

- the folder is automatically zipped up and the zip is attached
- all files in the folder are attached individually

I can't find a Thunderbird addon that will do this.

What could I try?

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the folder(s) and selecting multiple files to drop into the message. You'll now see that the files are all sitting as attachments in the window.

If you want them to be zipped as one, take a gander at the [Auto Zip](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4003) add-on. It'll zip your attachments and remove the individual files that are compressed into the new zip file sitting in their place.